# how to create 8 even columns in Bootstrap 3 with out gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a custom row which has 8 logos sat in even columns at the bottom of a page when sat at full size desktop (lg) I need them to work responsively.

I've tried a few options - 2 cols with 4 cols nested and 4 cols with 2 cols nested... the problem I have is the gutter creates extra spacing between columns which means the logos won't space evenly. Any experts have a better idea how I could place 8 logos spaced evenly in a row? perhaps creating a new 8 col custom grid?

Any help would be great.

Thanks
N

Comment: To close this topic you need to press the tick next to the question you prefer.

Answer (score 10):

**Bootstrap 3**

How about using a `list-inline` with 4 columns of 2 like this..

```
  <ul class="list-inline row"> 
    <li class="col-sm-3"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"></div></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"></div></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"></div></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"></div></li>
  </ul>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/90906

---

**Bootstrap 4**

Since Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, any number of equal width columns is now possible using the [auto-layout grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
        <div class="col">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/AOVGoJncei

Comment: Nice idea. works well. Thanks

There is also this css you can add to your bootstrap.

https://github.com/naeemshaikh27/Bootstrap-5-8-10

Answer (score 8):

2 columns 6   with each 4 colums 3 inside row-fluid

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! this is pretty much how I had it before but I missed out the secondary row class... so this all works nicely, the other problem I had was centering the logos on mobile (XS) instead of left justified.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it worked great thanks very much! I just need to figure out some CSS to center the logos when on mobile.

Comment: Nice ! To close this topic, could you accept the answer when your need will works ?

Answer (score 4):

Extending on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25023129/2266157

Here is a demonstration of an eight-wide Bootstrap row structure, with

### Equal padding (i.e. column gutters)...

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>No padding (.no-pad) on outermost columns (.col-md-6)<br></h2>

  <h3>Then nested columns can have padding...</h3>
  <div class="row no-pad">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col1</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col2</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col3</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col4</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col1</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col2</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col3</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col4</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### ...or indeed no column gutters.

```
<div class="container">    
  <h3>...or not</h3>
  <div class="row no-pad">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-pad">
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col1</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col2</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col3</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col4</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-pad">
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col1</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col2</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col3</i></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><i>col4</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This CSS is required in addition to Bootstrap

```
.row.no-pad {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

## Here is a working demo:
http://www.bootply.com/eWWpj3G9tL

### And the logo centring

To position the logos, I'd either use an `<img class="img-responsive">` or if they're smaller than the column width then you could CSS center them with `text-align:center` (or the bootstrap class `text-center` placed on the `.col-*`) or using the following CSS:

```
#logos img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i dunno why this was down voted, but you solved my problem greatly (my problem was different from the op one, but your solution with some small changes adapted greatly and offered a fresh way to style a single row into 2  column bootstrap compilant) thx mate!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is for a specific module so I would just create a simple new grid for this...

```
.eightLogos .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this but it didn't work it just kept the logos stacked. I would still like to keep a container and a row.

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple... Just add another column to your css.
Its best not to edit bootstrap CSS (and use a cdn).

So... We need to create the column css for all screen types.
I usually address 3 screen sizes which means creating 3 css sets for this column

1. big screens & normal screens
2. medium screens (ipad ext.)
3. small screens (mobile phones ext.)

**Decision time:**
Since we are talking about 8 columns which is a lot
its best to go with these css rules (in my opinion)

i almost always use a .container class for my designs which
makes big screen mode suitable in tablet unless in portrait mode.

**In short, Here are a good set of css rules**

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    eight-col {width: 50%; padding: 0 15px;}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    eight-col {width: 20%; padding: 0 15px;}
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    eight-col {float: left; width: 12.5%; margin: 0; padding: 0 5px;}
}
```

**Please note:**
i play around with padding as i see fit. Its best to leave some extra padding when in mobile mode but you can play around with it ;)