# How to remove the gutter (spacing) between columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I remove the 30px gutter between columns? But without setting `margin-left:-30px`?

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class='col-lg-1'></div>
    <div class='col-lg-1'></div>
    <div class='col-lg-1'></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 116):

**Update 2021**

**Bootstrap 5** the `.no-gutters` class has been replaced with `.g-0`. Use it on the `.row` where you want no spacing between columns.

Bootstrap 5 also has [new gutter classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) that are specifically designed to adjust the gutter for the entire row. The gutters classes can be used responsively for each breakpoint (ie: `gx-sm-4`)

- use `g-0` for no gutters
- use `g-(1-5)` to adjust horizontal & vertical gutters via spacing units
- use `gy-*` to adjust vertical gutters
- use `gx-*` to adjust horizontal gutters

**Bootstrap 4** now includes a `.no-gutters` class that you can just add to the `.row`.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4: http://codeply.com/go/OBW3RK1ErD

---

**Bootstrap 3.4.0+** gutters are created using padding, but they added a `.row-no-gutters` class. See the [documentation for Bootstrap 3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/) and look for 'Remove gutters'.

HTML you can use:

```html
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 3+, <= 3.3.9** gutters are created using padding. You also must adjust the negative margin so that spacing around the outer columns is not affected.

```css
.no-gutter {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.no-gutter > [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Just add the `no-gutter` class to the `.row`.

Demo: http://bootply.com/107458

Comment: Its good but its not working, maybe the order stylesheet is not ok. I have boostrap.css before the stylesheet where put I your solution. Its right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Did you also put the special `col` class in your HTML markup?

Comment: Do you understand the solution? The CSS is using '.col', so that you'd apply this to any columns for which you want the gutter removed. This way you can use it for cols other that `col-lg-1`

Comment: yes, I understand very well, its found.. Great job, thank you. Do you know some modern best practice source for develop theme bootstrap? thank you for answer.

Comment: but that's for ALL resolutions, right? you can't just have mobile version without gutters? :/

Answer (score 42):

A better way to remove padding on the columns would be to add a `.no-pad` class to your `.row`:

```
 <div class="row no-pad">
```

...and then add this CSS.

```
.row.no-pad {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

It's a bad idea to look for `first-` and `last-child` items as actually the `.row` is meant to take care of those offsets at the viewport's right and left. With the above method all `.col-*`s remain identically styled, which is also much simpler when considering responsiveness, especially stacking at mobile sizes (try my demo below `md` size).

The direct-descendant CSS selector `>` means that the `.no-pad` will only be applied to that `.row`'s immediate child `.col`s, so you can have padding on subsequently nested column structures (or not) if you wish.

Also using the attribute selector `[class*='col-']` means that each column needs no extra non-Bootstrap classes added.

### Here is a demo: http://www.bootply.com/Ae3xTyAW5D

Answer (score 4):

Instead of applying fixes that are difficult to maintain, I suggest generating your own customized version of Bootstrap from the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) where you can set the gutter to size you want (or remove it totally, by setting it to 0).

Comment: This isn't the greatest idea. What if there are some areas you want gutters, but other areas you do not?

Comment: You could use bootstrap mixins to generate another set of columns with or without the columns, or create your own simple ones manually

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 introduced the [`.row-no-gutters` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters) in v3.4.0, which works exactly as advertised.

To remove the gutters from a row and its columns, just add this class to the `<div>`.

Answer (score -1):

Change button link style.

```
<... class="bth btn-link noMarginPaddingBorder" ...>

.noMarginPaddingBorder{
    margin:0 !important; 
    padding:0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```