# bootstrap 2 div left space and height issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have created an html stuff with bootstrap 2.3.2 and not 3 The html is having one div with four child div's. The code is as given below

```
<div class="row-fluid column">
  <div class="span3 testOne">Sample One
                         <br>Sample One
                         <br>Sample One
  </div>
  <div class="span3 testTwo">Sample Two
  </div>
  <div class="span3 testThree">Sample Three
                           <br>Sample Three
                           <br>Sample Three
  </div>
  <div class="span3 testFour">Sample Four
  </div>
</div>
```

The code is working fine but I am facing two issues.

1. I am getting space in between the child div's
2. If one child div is big (containing more data) then the small div (containing less data) height is not proportional to the big one

[image]

what I expected to achieve is something like as shown below

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**Note:** **I can't use flex since it wont work in IE8, also I need to use bootstrap 2.3.2 with proper responsive**

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdv56voq/1/embedded/result/#Result)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: @Gareth Here I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 and not 3

Comment: and for the gutters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254889/how-can-i-remove-the-gutter-between-bootstrap-3-column

Comment: @Pamblam Here I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 and not bootstrap  3

Comment: Solutions 1 and 2 should both work from @Gareth link, as they should both work regardless of Bootstrap version and browser.

Comment: @Tricky12 can you update my jsfiddle

Comment: @AlexMan Sure! Here ya go! http://jsfiddle.net/gdv56voq/10/

Answer (score 0):

For css modify class as:

```
.column{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.testTwo{

    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;

}

.testThree{

    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The first issue can be solved by downloading the development version of Bootstrap. This has LESS files. Here you can go to /less/variables.less. The variable @gridGutterWidth is set to '20px'. If you make this '0px', the width between the columns will disappear.

You have to compile the less files. You can find out how here: http://lesscss.org/

2) The second issue is harder to solve. It's probably best to use solution #1 (using negative margins) from here:
[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: @Pamblam Unfortunately you can't do that for older Bootstrap versions. He needs to use the older version and as you can see, that isn't possible anymore. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

Comment: @Pamblam No problem. I also thought that downloading a customized version was the solution, so I went to find the url for him. Then I found out it wasn't possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a css tag such as `.nomargin{margin-left:0px!important;}` and add the class to the relevant divs `testOne, testTwo, testThree, testFour`and ensure the widths are set correctly

Comment: but in this case the child div's wont fill the parent div

Comment: Then i suggest editing the code above to '.nomargin{margin-left:0px!important;min-height:60px!important;}'  that way all your items have a minimumheight also. But remember to set the width accordingly.