# Remove spacing between cols

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the space between multiple columns in the Bootstrap grid.

How can we overwrite Bootstrap's CSS to achieve this task or any other better solution with pure CSS?

**main.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    // stuff here for this column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    // stuff here for columns
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 introduced `row-no-gutters` in v3.4.0 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254889/bootstrap-how-to-remove-the-gutter-between-columns (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

add a class when you need to remove spaces use it

```
.padding-0{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

in html write this class

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 padding-0">
       //stuff here for this column
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10 padding-0">
       //stuff here for columns
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the column will exceed row div

Comment: Thank you sir. I used `px-0` in Bootstrap v5.0 and the space removed. Your answer helped me a lot. @Morteza

Comment: How can remove the top and bottom space.?

Answer (score 75):

In **Bootstrap 5**, the `no-gutters` class has changed to `g-0`

In **Bootstrap 4**, the `no-gutters` class is included. No extra CSS is needed...

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    // stuff here for this column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    // stuff here for columns
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, use ```<div class="row g-0">``` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#no-gutters

Comment: did this affect the responsive view? @Zim

Answer (score 38):

In the Bootstrap 4 you can add class `mx-*` and `px-*`

```
<div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
        <p>Your content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
        <p>Your content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes of `mx-*` and `px-*` is in default bootstrap style, so you don't have to add it manually

`mx-*` stand for `margin-right: *` plus `margin-left: *`. While `px-*` stands for padding right and left.

There is also `my-* m-* mt-* mb-* mr-* ml-*` and `py-* p-* pt-* pb-* pr-* pl-*`.

Edit:

Bootstrap 5 used `ps-* pe-* ms-* me-*` and dropped `pl-* pr-* ml-* mr-*`. It uses "start" and "end" instead of "left" and "right".

Comment: Where I can find references abut this?

Comment: Bootstrap docs under Spacing section https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Most helpful answer.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 has also ```<div class="row g-0">``` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#no-gutters

Answer (score 14):

You can create a class `no-gutter` for your `row` and remove the margin/padding that's added by bootstrap, like suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489307/how-to-remove-gutter-space-for-a-specific-div-only-bootstrap/21282059#21282059):

```css
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.row > div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

I've set a gray background and a border for demonstration purposes. Watch the result in fullscreen to see, that there is no space anymore between the columns. More information about the predefined margin and padding in Bootstrap can be [found here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Comment: I found this the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: This solution seems close to answering the question, but I think the author was most concerned about the "internal" space between columns and this removes padding everywhere. I would suggest a modification to your selector to pick columns except the first and last: .row.no-internal-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child).

Answer (score 4):

As of BootStrap 5, here is how to remove `gutter`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

```
<div class="row g-0">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to the row and target the column children with a descendant wildcard selector:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        //stuff here for this column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        //stuff here for columns
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nopadding > div[class^="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Still, the columns will go out of the row. Add an additional css : .nopadding{margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;} to keep the columns inside the row.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LESS you can use snippet and apply it to the row.

```
.no-gutter {
   [class*="col-"] {
       padding-left: 0 !important;
       padding-right: 0 !important;
   }
}
```

If normal CSS

```
.no-gutter > [class*="col-"]{
}
```

Like so:

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   //stuff here for this column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
   //stuff here for columns
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the columns there is a 15px padding on either side, if you remove that they should sit together.

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

This snippet is from modifed code found in grid-framework.less.

Answer (score 1):

Simple add .no-gutter on row.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Anshuman actually works! It gets rid of the bootstrap column spaces when you set the padding to zero in the styles, i.e padding: 0;

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-3" style= "padding:0;">
    //html code here..
  </div>
  <div class = "col-sm-3" style= "padding:0;">
    //html code here..
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5** replace `no-gutters` class has changed to `g-0`