# Why table does add additional space on both left and right sides?

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a `<div>` and I want to set the table `width` 100% of its parent div. Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row custom-row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 title">
                                <strong>Shift</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 custom-table">
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>heading1</th>
                                        <th>heading2</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr><td>cell11 </td> <td> cell12</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>cell21 </td> <td> cell22</td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

My expectation is so simple. Table width should be exactly same as `col-md-10 custom-table`. I am trying this as soon below:

```
.custom-table table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but there are some spaces on the left and right side of the table as like the following picture:

[image]

you can see the div with red mark box and I set `1px solid` border on the table to visualize table width. Why the table is not being scratched to fit its parent div width. I checked the padding, margin on div or table. there is no padding or margin. Any Idea?

Comment: Surely if you go on Google Dev tools, you'll be able to see where the padding is?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, then the padding might be coming from the class col-md-10

Comment: [remove the gutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254889/bootstrap-how-to-remove-the-gutter-between-columns)?

Comment: Thanks @JoseGuerra you save my life. The padding was coming from bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to your existing CSSes. Add `!important` only if you need it.

```
.custom-table {
     padding: 0 !important;
}
```